# How to disable past dates for date range in Eonasdan bootstrap datetimepicker?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I have to disable past dates in Eonasdan bootstrap datetimepicker v4, 
My Code is :

```
$('input#startDate,input#endDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss',
    startDate: new Date()
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    minDate:new Date()
});
```

Comment: Can you mark it as answer so that others can refer it

Comment: This `new Date()` is getting current client's time, how can I set current date by server date in php? I have been written `<?php echo "<script>var today = '" .date('Y-m-d H:i:s'). "';</script>?>` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work. I have to use `minDate:new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)`

Comment: Works great. Tested on v4.17.43. However, this should be made easily accessible in the official documentation.